# Springs on a pulley... When to use?

Tags: springs, pulleys, machine-design

I saw a machine that fed a sheet of laminate through some rollers.  The motor had a pulley attached to its shaft, and a spring connected to the pulley.  Why not use a belt?  Wouldnt the spring make it too difficult to know the exact position of the load on the other side of the spring?

Comment: A picture would help or diagram, as a spring can be used to control tension on the belt.

Comment: It may be more import to prevent spikes in force applied to the laminate and thus prevent slippage than to know its exact position at any given time - the overall travel distance of the laminate is known from the number of rotations, and if it’s moving at a constant speed then the error from the spring will be small compared to the number of rotations being counted.